# Clearing multiple timeouts in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using React for practice, I'm trying to build a small notification system that disappears after a given period using timeouts.

A sample scenario;

1. User creates one notification and wait for it's to expire
2. The cleanup function runs from useEffect and clears the timeout.

This would be no problem and clears out the only available timeout. The problem appears when I'm adding more:

1. Render #1 - adding the first notification
2. Render #2 - the cleanup function calls from render #1 for adding a new notification. This adds a new notification but clears a timeout before it's done.
3. The timeout expires from render #2 so runs the cleanup function and clears the right timeout.

It's a fairly simple component, which renders a array of objects (with the timeout in it) from a Zustand store.

```
export const Notifications = () => {   const { queue, } = useStore()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!queue.length || !queue) return

    // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
    return () => {
      const { timeout } = queue[0]

      timeout && clearTimeout(timeout)
    }   }, [queue])

  return (
    <div className="absolute bottom-0 mb-8 space-y-3">
      {queue.map(({ id, value }) => (
        <NotificationComponent key={id} requestDiscard={() => id}>
          {value}
        </NotificationComponent>
      ))}
    </div>   ) }
```

My question is; is there any way to not delete a running timeout when adding a new notification? I also tried finding the last notification in the array by `queue[queue.length - 1]`, but it somehow doesn't make any sense

My zustand store:

```
interface State {
  queue: Notification[]
  add: (notification: Notification) => void
  rm: (id: string) => void
}

const useNotificationStore = c<State>(set => ({
  add: (notification: Notification) =>
    set(({ queue }) => ({ queue: [...queue, notification] })),
  rm: (id: string) =>
    set(({ queue }) => ({
      queue: queue.filter(n => id !== n.id),
    })),
  queue: [],
}))
```

My hook for adding notifications;

```
export function useStoreForStackOverflow() {
  const { add, rm } = useNotificationStore()

  const notificate = (value: string) => {
    const id = nanoid()
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => rm(id), 2000)

    return add({ id, value, timeout })
  }

  return { notificate }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think with a minor tweak/refactor you can instead use an array of queued timeouts. Don't use the `useEffect` hook to manage the timeouts other than using a single mounting `useEffect` to return an unmounting cleanup function to clear out any remaining running timeouts when the component unmounts.

Use `enqueue` and `dequeue` functions to start a timeout and enqueue a stored payload and timer id, to be cleared by the dequeue function.

```
const [timerQueue, setTimerQueue] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  return () => timerQueue.forEach(({ timerId }) => clearTimeout(timerId));
}, []);

const enqueue = (id) => {
  const timerId = setTimeout(dequeue, 3000, id);
  setTimerQueue((queue) =>
    queue.concat({
      id,
      timerId
    })
  );
};

const dequeue = (id) =>
  setTimerQueue((queue) => queue.filter((el) => el.id !== id));
```

Demo

[image: Edit clearing-multiple-timeouts-in-useeffect]

Comment: It obviously works, but I don't understand how this is different from my Zustand store? I also store and filter out? I updated my answer with my store.

Comment: @Bas I see, yes, very similar code indeed. It seems the difference is most what I called out, not using the `useEffect` hook to clear timers when the state updates, but instead using the timeout expiring to invoke the remove/dequeue function.

Comment: I added my code for adding/removing notifications; where I think I'm doing the same in my setTimeout function. I something different? I think I lost it, is it the payload on the timer?

Comment: @Bas Yes, but each time you update the `queue` state you are clearing the timeout of the 0th element in the queue. You only want to clear it from the queue if (a) timeout expires, or (b) component unmounts and you are clearing the entire queue.

Comment: I see! Thank you, there's one thing, I updated it to yours, but I noticed the missing dependencies on useEffect. I added that (https://codesandbox.io/s/clearing-multiple-timeouts-in-useeffect-forked-ppl2z) and noticed the same behaviour. Only the last get's removed. Why is that?

Comment: Also after some debugging I noticed the useEffect function (and cleanup func) not even running when not having that dependency.

Comment: @Bas That is supposed to be an empty dependency array so it only clears the queue's saved timeout ids when unmounting. If you are familiar with class components we are effectively using `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method equivalent. If you add the queue to the dependency then each time the queue updates you clear ***all*** the previously saved timeout ids.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239568/discussion-between-bas-and-drew-reese).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useRef` here to track all timeouts in a `Map`.

The cool thing about `Map` is that you can use your Notification as key and the timer as value.

I created a small POC with useState but it should also work fine with Zustand:
https://codesandbox.io/s/young-worker-hg38x

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {

  const [notifications, setNotification] = useState<{message: string}[]>([]);
  const timers = useRef(new Map());

  useEffect(() => {
    const newNotifications = notifications.filter((notification) => !timers.current.has(notification));
    newNotifications.forEach((newNotification) => {
      timers.current.set(newNotification, setTimeout(() => {
        // Remove notification
        setNotification((currentNotifications) => currentNotifications.filter((notification) => notification !== newNotification));
        // Remove notification from timer tracker:
        timers.current.delete(newNotification)
      }, 3000));
    });
  }, [notifications])

  // Clear all timers on unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      [...timers.current.values()].forEach((timer) => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {notifications.map((notification) => <p>{notification.message}</p>)}
      <button onClick={() => {
        setNotification([...notifications, {
          message: 'notification' + Math.random()
        }]);
      }}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```